# nginx proxy inside another in subdirectory

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get the below configuration to work in Nginx, basically reset is another web application that is part of the much larger application that resets the database of the larger one.

Currently whenever i try to visit domain.com/reset/ it's taking the path as domain.com/ and then passing to the server there that it needs the response for /reset/.

tldr; http://domain.com/reset/ is triggering the third location block and not the first.

```
    location /reset/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9091;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /reset/media {
        alias /home/jsoft/reset/srv/static/;
        expires 1y;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick sample config removing all the dynamic parts to test that very basic feature of nginx that location matching is:

```
location /reset {
    return 200 "reset";
}

location /reset/media {
    return 200 "reset media";
}

location / {
    return 200 "default";
}
```

If the right locations are triggered, then you can put your dynamic content back as they won't have an impact.

Ensure your configuration is applied by:

1. Testing it with `nginx -t`
2. Checking your error log after having issued `service nginx reload` for any error making the reload to fail

Once you have tested the locations properly and you switched back to the configuration you provided, any following error is most probably coming from the backend or the way you configured nginx talks to it, but not the locations themselves.